# Convert FDF file content into PDF readable format as attachment using APEX

Tags: salesforce

I have an FDF format attachment which needs to be converted into PDF format attachment. I am facing issues while reading the FDF file content.

Comment: This is probably not answerable at present. What issues are you facing, eg?

Comment: Without more information with what you have tried and what you are trying to do this question is probably not going to get answered and will probably get closed for being off topic

Answer (score 0):

I believe FDF formatted files are not text files.  While you can technically read any file in Apex, you will not be able to parse the file, since it's in a format designed to be ready by an Adobe product.
The only way to work with this from Apex would be to run the [Acrobat Forms Data Format Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) on another server and then perform a callout from Apex to the other server.  Apex itself will not be able to work with the format.
This concept of running a web service as a form of middleware is commonly used and Apex does make it very easy to perform callouts.